# T-SQL Query: Select only the most recent row (for each computer name)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table named `ComputerStatus` in a SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition database, that looks like the following:

```
ComputerName       Status          Timestamp
------------       -----------     ------------
client01           Online          2013-04-11 11:00 AM
client01           Online          2013-04-08 10:00 AM
client01           Offline         2013-04-05 09:00 PM
client02           Offline         2013-04-08 10:00 AM
client02           Online          2013-04-03 10:00 AM
client03           Online          2013-04-02 10:00 AM
client03           Offline         2013-04-05 10:00 PM
client03           Online          2013-04-03 12:00 PM
```

What I want to do is get the most recent (based on `Timestamp`) row for each unique computer name. Although I am quite amateur with SQL Server queries, I know that I can:

- Write a stored procedure that retrieves the most recent entry (for a single computer), and then use a cursor to call the procedure multiple times
- Use the following T-SQL code (in the stored procedure) to retrieve the latest row: `select top 1 * from ComputerStatus where ComputerName = 'client01' order by Timestamp descending`

### Desired Result

```
ComputerName       Status          Timestamp
------------       -----------     ------------
client01           Online          2013-04-11 11:00 AM
client02           Offline         2013-04-08 10:00 AM
client03           Offline         2013-04-05 10:00 PM
```

I know how to select the most recent row for a single computer. The part I'm struggling with is how to do this for all unique computers in the table. Does this require that I use a SQL cursor, to iterate over the unique computer names in the table? Or, is there a more efficient way of achieving these results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by using RowNumber which gives a row number to every row. Since you want to give row number starting from 1 for each computerName based on TimeStamp, we need to partition it by Computername

```
select * from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ComputerName order by Timestamp desc) as rno 
from ComputerStatus
) as T where rno = 1
```

### [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this - I will mark the answer when StackOverflow allows me to in 8 minutes. It looks like I need to research SQL partitioning and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: There is an 'AS' clause missing after the last parenthesis. Should be ") as ComputerStatus where rno = 1". Could also use an alias instead such as ") as compStat where rno = 1"

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be something like this:

```
    SELECT cs1.*
    FROM ComputerStatus cs1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT ComputerName, MAX(Timestamp) as [Timestamp] 
                  FROM ComputerStatus
                  GROUP BY ComputerName) cs2
      ON cs1.ComputerName=cs2.ComputerName and cs1.Timestamp = cs2.Timestamp
```

The sub-query will find the computer name and most recent timestamp, then the outer-query will use that data and match it to the Status.

But I do prefer using ROW_NUMBER().  So convenient!

Comment: This is a great idea. Thank you for posting this alternative. Good job.

Comment: I actually just came back to this, and realized that this particular answer lacks the ability to select all columns, because of the `GROUP BY` clause. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: The sub-query's `group by` clause limits that sub-query's select statement, but as long as you join it properly on the same table (like above), it will be able to select all columns.  That said, the row_number really is the better solution.